# Django как вывести всех пользователей

Tags: python, django, webview, шаблоны, views

Только начал работу с django. Столкнулся с трудностью, не могу получить список всех пользователей. есть начальная страница base.html в которую пытаюсь встроить вывод этих пользователей но все бесполезно... в корневой папке teamplates/ в файле base.html:

```
..... 
{% for users in users_list %}
<p>
    {{ account.username }}
    {{ account.profile_image }}
</p>
{% endfor %} 
......
```

так же для надежности создал файл /account/teamplates/account/AllUsers.html но когда на него перехожу в браузере то ошибка

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  {% for users in users_list %}

      <div class="UsersList">
          {{ account.username }}
          {{account.profile_image }} }}
      </div>

  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Так же, есть класс Account из которого я хочу взять username и profile_image в каталоге account/models.py:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
```

account/views.py:

```
def AllUsers(request):
    users_list = Account.objects.all()

    context = {
            "users_list": users_list,
            "username": account.username,
            "profile_image": account.profile_image,
        }
    return render(request, 'account/AllUsers.html', context)
```

account/urls.py:

```
    from account.views import AllUsers

urlpatterns = [

    path('AllUsers/', AllUsers, name="AllUsers")]
```

После этого сделал makemigrations и migrate. Runserver - 0 ошибок - пользователи не выведены.

Comment: а почему вы в цикле пишете `for users`, а обращаетесь к `accounts`?

Comment: Я просто пробовал миллион способов, и в этот момент перестал понимать что я пытаюсь сделать, поэтому пришел с таким кодом сюда.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы итерируете по списку users_list с помощью переменной users, то к ней вы и должны обращаться:

```
{% for users in users_list %}
<p>
    {{ users.username }}
    {{ users.profile_image }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: попробовал, соответственно ничего не поменялось. но за замечание спасибо, буду внимательней

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block content %}
  {% for users in users_list %}

      <div class="UsersList">
          {{ account.username }}
          {{account.profile_image }} }}
      </div>      </div>

  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

```
..... 
{% for users in users_list %}
<p>
    {{ account.username }}
    {{ account.profile_image }}
</p>
{% endfor %} 
......
```

В данных участках кода, в частности в цикле for Вы итерируете users, а в разметке Вы рендерите account.username, при том что переменной account не существует. Так же я бы хотел указать на то, что имя переменной users не самаое подходящее имя для сущности, которая является пользователем. На мой взгляд, лучше сменить это имя на user.

Comment: Вы все правильно описали в текстовой части ответа, но зачем вы просто скопировали неправильный код автора вопроса, а не предложили исправленный? Кроме того, ваш ответ в принципе не отличается от моего.

Comment: Я процитировал код, в котором у автора ошибка, указав в чем именно.

Comment: ничего не вывелось, к сожалению...